# VBscript to do a recursive search for multiple files with different names and output their path to a text file

Tags: vbscript

Ok so I need to search multiple computers for certain files that may indicate an infection. I want to use a vbscript that I can just drop in the C:\ folder and let it run and it creates a text file for the out put. I have 13 different file names to look for. I've looked around for vbscripts that do this, but all I can find are ones for just one specific file, or for a certain file time. I can't find a recursive search for multiple specific files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post an attempt and I'll help you get it working.  This is a pretty basic task.  No one is going to want to answer this if you don't put a little effort into it.

Comment: I switched from a vbscript and just used a batch file. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a dir and pipe that to findstr. The example here uses literals but you can use regular expresssions. Check findstr help for usage.

```
Dim command, objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
command = "CMD.EXE /c dir/s/b | findstr /L /C:""txt"" /C:""exe""  > 1.txt"
objShell.Run command, , true
Set objShell = Nothing
```